# NET Core single-file deploying in docker: а какой будет ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, развертывание

Обычно при публикации NET Core приложения в докер-контейнере происходит примерно следующее:

1. собираю приложение для целевой платформы, например, командой вида

   ```
    dotnet publish --runtime linux-musl-x64 --self-contained true -c Release
   ```

(Рантайм в этой команде соответсвует сборке для alpain)

2. Запускаю построение образа командой

   ```
    docker build -t demo-image -f Dockerfile .
   ```

где докерфайл выглядит примерно так:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0

COPY publish-output/* /App/

WORKDIR /App

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ddemo.dll"]
```

3. И потом я запускаю контейнер командой наподобие этой:

   ```
    docker run -it --name demo-cont  -p 1080:80 --restart unless-stopped -d demo-image
   ```

И тут я [прочитал](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli ) про публикацию в виде одного файла, когда вместо более 300 файлов в директории publish образуется всего три файла: один огромный с именем Ddemo, и пара json-ов ( appsettings.json и appsettings.Development.json )

Очень красиво. Очень удобно. Очень круто.

Но... *здесь возникает ключевой вопрос*.

Раньше у меня в папке лежала отдельная DLL-ка, которая и была в докерфайле ENTRYPOINT

(см. последнюю строку докер-файла)

**А теперь что я должен стартовать в докер-контейнере?**
То есть, что мне надо в докерфайле прописать в секции ENTRYPOINT?

Гугление по ключевым словам - не привело к результатам...

Спасибо заранее за подсказки!

Comment: а что принципиально поменялось? был файл Ddemo и остался файл Ddemo

Comment: Уважаемый Grundy, спасибо, Вы не раз уже помогали мне советами! Но есть проблема: был файл Ddemo.dll, и запускался он последней командой в докерфайле:  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ddemo.dll"] Теперь есть огромный "архив" Ddemo (без расширения), но запуск его тем же способом ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ddemo"]  - не работает, говорит "ошибка, не могу найти файл или не NET-сборка". Дописывание chmod +x Ddemo - не помогает. Может, его надо запускать уже без dotnet в команде ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: попробуй параметр [ready to run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run) выставить

Comment: А точно без расширения файл выходит?

Comment: Точно без расширения. я могу вечером расписать всё с максимальной подробностью, пока - просто скажу: да, получается один файл без расширения. И есть написать последней строкой в Dockerfile команду ENTRYPOINT ["Ddemo"]  (то есть, без dotnet) - то то же ругается "/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:290: starting container process caused "exec: \"Ddemo\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: Йес! Йес! Йес! Ошибка была элементарной, меня, как обычно, подвело моё виндовое прошлое... Команда запуска - вот такая:  ENTRYPOINT ["./Ddemo"]

Comment: Если разобрался - напиши ответ :)

Comment: `self-contained` означает, что в приложение "вшит" рантайм, т.е. теоретически вы можете использовать образ `runtime-deps` вместо `aspnet`.